# having Unexpected "" character error in string interpolation

Tags: xcode, swift, string-interpolation

for some reason, I can't get the expression work. what am I missing? :(
[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        // Configure the cell...
        if(indexPath.section == 0){

            cell.textLabel!.text =  searchActive == true ? "\(csFilter[indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())" : "\(subjectPerSection["CS"]![indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())";

        }
        else if( indexPath.section == 1){
            cell.textLabel!.text =  searchActive == true ? "\(seaFilter[indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())" : "\( subjectPerSection["SEA"]![indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())";
        }
        else if( indexPath.section == 2){
            cell.textLabel!.text =  searchActive == true ? "\(humFilter[indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())" : "\( subjectPerSection["HUM"]![indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())";
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @LeoDabus you mean \String(subjectPerSection["CS"]!) ?

Comment: @LeoDabus tried using that but I'm getting "use of unresolved indentifier'CS' at ' \(subjectPerSection[String(CS)]!)'

Comment: Btw to compare a Bool to true it is redundant. Just drop `== true`

Comment: You can also use the plus operator to concatenate your strings

Comment: What Xcode / Swift version are you using? Literal quotes in string interpolation aren't allowed until in one of the most recent versions. A workaround is to use a variable to retrieve the dictionary value.

Comment: Another point you have to make sure to unwrap your dictionary values safely

Comment: @LeoDabus lol i never thought about that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have quotes inside your string.  They need to be "escaped" to work.

e.g. `...rSection[\"CS\"]![indexPa...`.

(I take that back.  I answered too quickly.)

I would suggest expanding the ternary operator ?: into a full blown "if" statement and using intermediate variables until you get it working and then collapse it down again afterwards.

Comment: Tried adding escape "\", but it still shows the error :(

 "\(subjectPerSection[\"CS\"]![indexPath.row].returnFullDescription())"; `

Comment: @phenomenon09 but another error ... check how you use ! operator.